# The menu items in my bootstrap navbar are stacking vertically instead of horizontally, How to fix?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm following Youtube videos to learn Bootstrap and although I'm following along exactly what they are doing I'm still getting a different result.

Following this Youtube video - [Bootstrap Tutorial for Beginners - 6 - Navbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNAqaNQc2qk&index=6&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBPw1sFodruZUPheWVKchlM)

I've made a navbar but the items are stacking vertically in the top right corner instead of being displayed inline.

I can't find any typos that could be causing this and if I've followed the video perfectly then maybe bootstrap has changed since this video was made?

**Code**

```html
<!-- video #6 Navigation -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
  <!-- Logo -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PROJECTBOOTSTRAP</a>
   </div>
  
  <!-- Menu Items -->
   <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#grid-system">Grid System</a></li>
     <li><a href="#text-styling">Text-styling</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tables">Tables</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line in your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

See full page of snippet.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
  <!-- Logo -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PROJECTBOOTSTRAP</a>
   </div>
  
  <!-- Menu Items -->
   <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#grid-system">Grid System</a></li>
     <li><a href="#text-styling">Text-styling</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tables">Tables</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```